# Preventing Jersey log from logging in catalina.out

Tags: jersey

I have following code to create Jersey client (**my application is using an older version of Jersey**).

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out))
```

The problem: my application is using Log4J but Jersey is printing the logs using JUL . That is the reason my catalina.out is getting bloated because Jersey is writing byte array of PDF files .

I ***tested after removing the second line*** (`client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out))`) and it is no longer printing in catalina.out . Can you please suggest if it is a safe approach ?